# Public Sub not Passing Variables to Other Modules

Tags: vba, excel

I have made a macro to pull send an email to certain people based on the Value of a cell being X. The problem is that all the variables that I declared in one modules do not properly pass to the Email module. Neither module was made outside of the Modules tab within the project so that should not be the issue. I have named the macros as public which I thought prevented this issue from arising but it does not seem to be working. Are there any ideas? Attached is the relevant code.

```
Public Sub Decision_Making_Parts_Recieved()

Worksheets("Parts Email Update").Activate

i = 2

Do

'Exits if part Number is not Present (End of List)
If Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
Exit Do
Else
End If

'Determines if Part is Marked To Be Emailed, if so, it Remembers the Contact Name For the Part
If Cells(i, 4) = "x" Or Cells(i, 4) = "X" Then
Current_Contact_Name = Cells(i, 3)
Current_Part_Number = Cells(i, 1)
Else
End If


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Activates the Worksheet Containing Variable Email Contact data
Worksheets("Contacts").Activate

'Search Contacts sheet for Name and finds Paired Email Address
A = 2
Do

'Exits if Name is not Present (End of List)
If Cells(A, 1) = "" Then
Exit Do
Else
End If

If Cells(A, 1) = Current_Contact_Name Then
Current_Contact_Address = Cells(A, 3)
Current_Contact_Role = Cells(A, 2)
Exit Do
Else
End If

A = A + 1
Loop
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Activates the Worksheet Containing Variable Email Setup data
Worksheets("Email Setup").Activate

'Creates Email Based on the Role of the Current Contact
If Current_Contact_Role = Range("B2") Then
Email_Subject = Range("A2") & " " & Current_Part_Number & " " & Range("E2")
Email_Body = Range("A4") & " " & Current_Part_Number & " " & Range("F2")
Else
End If


Call Email_Macro

'-----------------------------------------------------------------
'Updates the Parts sheet and Changes "x" (Send) to "S" (Sent)
Worksheets("Parts Email Update").Activate
Cells(i, 4) = "S"

'Resets the Variables
Current_Contact_Name = ""
Current_Part_Number = ""
Current_Contact_Address = ""
Current_Contact_Role = ""


i = i + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

And here is the module I want it passed to

```
Public Sub Email_Macro()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = Email_Body

'& vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
 '         "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
  '        "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
   '       "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
    '      "This is line 4"

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
'Adresses the Email to the Variable
    .To = Current_Contact_Address
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Email_Subject
    .Body = strbody
    'You can add a file like this
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    .Send   'or use .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Dee, thanks for the response, I am not familiar with what you mean by the declaration of the variable Email_Macro. Are you saying I need to declare this somewhere before I call it?

Comment: OK, so this might be the problem. Try to use [Option Explicit](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html) statement.

Comment: So you fill e.g. Email_Body variable inside of Decision_Making_Parts_Recieved method which is located in module 1. And you want to use this variable inside of method Email_Macro which is located in module 2. Do I understand it correctly? Could you show the declaration of this variable Email_Body? How and when do you call the method Email_Macro?

Comment: Read this http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx Btw you are not passing anything to the second procedure as it has no parameters. You could add them to get round your problem.

Comment: I tried using Option Explicit and defining the variables as strings and integers but that did not seem to work either

Comment: _Where_ are the variables like `Email_Body` declared? Needs to be at [module level](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/variable-scope.html).

Comment: A couple options, 1) make a Global variables Modules with subs to handle/initialize them, you will always want to do this on workbook startup or another event. 2) move the two subs into the same module and declare the variables under Option Explicit but prior to subs - Global to Module only 3) Pass the variables back and forth between modules as arguments, they will only exist locally to the scope of the module passed into, a function returns data so you could switch to that methodology.  var = function call (argument).  Depends on how you code and how big your project is.

Comment: Public just means the sub can be called from outside of its module easily, you can also call privates but differently, it does not apply to the variables definition scope.

Answer (score 0):

@Jordan
I realize like most of us you are likely in a hurry, but sometimes thinking things through with some planning is a great alternative to the headaches that can be caused later.

This screen shot shows you how to "quickly" although I will not say it is the best way to get global access to these variables.  As you move forward you should try and keep the scope of variables to a sub level if not a module level, for the simple fact you will find that you do not need very many global variables and it will also help you maintain your code if it gets huge and sprawling:

Approach 1: Global to the Project
[image]
In a dedicated module for global variables so you always know where they are:

```
Option Explicit

Public Current_Part_Number As String
Public Current_Contact_Name As String
Public Current_Contact_Address As String
Public Current_Contact_Role As String
Public Email_Subject As String
Public Email_Body As String

Private Sub initGlobalVars()

Current_Part_Number = ""
Current_Contact_Name = ""
Current_Contact_Address = ""
Current_Contact_Role = ""
Email_Subject = ""
Email_Body = ""

End Sub
```

Don't forget to initialize them in some way, don't count on your functions, what if you change them up?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

'Calling a private function stands out, it is deliberate
Application.Run "Global_Vars.initGlobalVars"
End Sub
```

You will notice that I also named the sheets, a method for you to embrace is to wrap your worksheet scope as well.

Here I will do it with a piece of your code, here I will also replace the Do which you seem to be using as flow control, maybe think about your flow, it's not my style to use Do-Loop like that but it might be yours

```
Option Explicit
'Warning: GLOBAL VARIABLES USED
' Current_Contact_Name
' Current_Part_Number

Public Sub Decision_Making_Parts_Recieved()

Dim i As Double ' surely you do not want a global i

'you know what worksheet you are working on in this code block
With wsPartsEmailSetup

    i = 2

    'Exits if part Number is not Present (End of List)
    If .Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
        GoTo JumpOut
    Else 'Do Nothing
    End If

    'Determines if Part is Marked To Be Emailed, if so, it Remembers the Contact Name For the Part
    If .Cells(i, 4) = "x" Or .Cells(i, 4) = "X" Then 
    'If UCase(.Cells(i, 4)) = "X" Then
        Current_Contact_Name = .Cells(i, 3)
        Current_Part_Number = .Cells(i, 1)
    Else 'Do Nothing
    End If

End With

'Your flow control goes here, Sorry I don't use do very often, can be hard to follow
JumpOut:

'(more code) . .. maybe more jumpout places
End Sub
```

There is also a UCase function so UCase(.Cells(i, 4)) = "X" would cover both "x" and "X"

Maybe this helps you today.  Maybe it makes you think about some things tomorrow.

You could always move your subs into one module if your code is short and declare them at the top, they will be global module scope here, you will not be able to use them outside of this module. Don't forget to initialize them, you have to take care of them now, that is part of the trouble with not releasing at sub or module scope, you have to manage the states.

APPROACH 2:

```
Option Explicit
'inside of my module


Dim Current_Part_Number As String
Dim Current_Contact_Name As String
Dim Current_Contact_Address As String
Dim Current_Contact_Role As String
Dim Email_Subject As String
Dim Email_Body As String

Public Sub mySub1()

'do stuff with global module level variables

End Sub

Public Sub mySub2()

'do stuff with global module level variables

End Sub
```

Approach 3 would be to pass them in as arguments to subs (or functions if you are going to return something back to the caller).  I don't have time to mock that one up with your code right now.

Get in there and have fun.